# Raspberry pi 3 and pi camera ...Green tint in the video

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I have rasp 3 and a new [picamera](http://www.amazon.in/Raspberry-Pi-Camera-Board/dp/B00L1FOIIS?_encoding=UTF8&portal-device-attributes=desktop&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00).

When i was checking the video, I get the green tint. I tried things like reconnecting the hardware well but no got change.

please help

Comment: As far as the green tint is concerned,  the problem may be with the ribbon, the ribbon may not be seated properly in the connecter. After adjusting the ribbon connection, the output will be better. if not try the following

 turn white-balance off (--awb off). Using '--awb sun' .

However the truth is that the cable does not sit firmly so this might be an issue also.

Comment: I bought raspicam V2 and it was working fine without green tint. It seems that raspi 3 is compatible with  raspicamV2

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry pi3 is compatible with picamera V2 . The tint didnt show up when the V2 cam was used.